# Exibir apenas comentários feitos em posts de autores no WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Por padrão o Wordpress mostra para todas as contas **todos** os comentários que o site já recebeu.

Queria que quando estivesse logado como `Autor` somente mostrasse comentários feitos em posts do `Autor`.

Veja:

Os comentários com contorno verde são os que foram feitos em posts criados pela minha conta de `Autor` o resto são comentários feitos em posts de outros `Autores`.

O que eu queria é que mostrasse apenas os comentários feitos em meus posts.

Alguém conhece algum **PLUGIN** que faça isso?

Pesquisei bastante na internet e não achei nada útil.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> Achei esse **[Tópico](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/restricting-users-to-seeing-only-comments-on-their-posts-in-admin)** que contém o seguinte código:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# Ensure that non-admins can see and manage only their own comments
# ------------------------------------------------------------

function myplugin_get_comment_list_by_user($clauses) {
    if (is_admin()) {
        global $user_ID, $wpdb;
        $clauses['join'] = ", wp_posts";
        $clauses['where'] .= " AND wp_posts.post_author = ".$user_ID." AND wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID";
    };
    return $clauses;
};
// ensure that editors and admins can moderate everything
if(!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) {
add_filter('comments_clauses', 'myplugin_get_comment_list_by_user');
}
```

Coloquei em `functions.php` porém simplesmente some todos os comentários:

Não funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adaptado [desta resposta no WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56657/12615). Como sempre, em vez de colocar o código em `functions.php`, fazemos um plugin para incluir essa nova funcionalidade, já que não queremos que isso suma se trocarmos o tema.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Mostrar comentários somente do usuário logado 
 * Plugin URI:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26773/201
 * Description: Baseado em https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56657/12615. Código revisado e comentado em português.
 * Author:      Rutwick Gangurde, brasofilo
 * License:     GPLv3
 */

# Aplicar somente no backend
if( is_admin() )
    add_filter( 'the_comments', 'wpse56652_filter_comments' );

function wpse56652_filter_comments( $comments )
{
    # Confirmar que estamos na página correta
    global $pagenow;
    if( $pagenow !== 'edit-comments.php' )
        return $comments;

    # Confirmar que o usuário não é administrador
    ## Ver http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table
    global $user_ID;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if( current_user_can( 'create_users' ) )
        return $comments;

    # Ok, página correta, usuário não é admin: limpar comentários que não são do usuário logado
    foreach( $comments as $i => $comment )
    {
        $the_post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );
        if( $comment->user_id != $user_ID  && $the_post->post_author != $user_ID ) 
            unset( $comments[$i] );
    }

    return $comments;
}
```

Para ficar completo, é necessário ajustar a contagem de comentários:

[image]

E [esta resposta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77024/12615) serve como ponto de partida para fazer o código complementar.

Comment: Não é um erro. O negócio é que estão aparecendo os comentários que `O Teste da Silva` fez, mesmo que ele não seja o autor do post. Se quiser modificar isso, remova `$comment->user_id != $user_ID  &&` de dentro do `if()`. . . . PS: por favor, delete os comentários que não tem a ver com o problema, deixando a resposta mais limpa pros futuros leitores ;)

Comment: Uma dúvida: Já que também fica os comentários que o próprio `Autor` fez em posts de outros autores, teria como ele editar também esses comentários? Pois como está não é possível.

Comment: Este código não tem nada a ver com isso. Não tenho certeza qual o motivo...

Comment: Olha isso: http://prntscr.com/47a5f2 você é 10! rsrs

Comment: Não tem muito jeito, você precisa dar a *capability* `edit_comment` ao *role*.